# Class import from another .py file

Tags: python

This is my first question here so please don't roast me if it seems obvious or stupid ;)

I've started learning Python two months ago and I'm trying to get my head wrapped around some basic functions of this language.

I've created a script that creates a basic blockchain and generates a QR code at the end. I've created the following class:

```
class BlobChang:
    def __init__(self, string=None, rand=None, conc=None, ha=None, blobchang=''):
        self.string = string
        self.rand = rand
        self.conc = conc
        self.ha = ha
        self.blobchang = blobchang

    def input(self):
        self.string = input('Input: ')

    def h(self):
        self.rand = str(random.randrange(1, 1000))
        self.conc = self.string + self.rand
        self.ha = hashlib.sha256(self.string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        self.blobchang = self.blobchang + self.ha
        print(self.blobchang)
```

I've named that script BlobChang.py. In the same directory I've created a new Python file import_test.py and I've imported the BlobChang class:

`from BlobChang import BlobChang`

I've created an instance of this class named test:

```
test = BlobChang()
```

and it worked fine. I did test.input() and it worked, then test.h() and this worked as well but then something weird happened. The script instead of finishing started executing the remainder of the original code from BlobChang.py! It looks like this:

```
check_continue = input('Want to create a BlobChang? (Y/N): \n')
while if_yes(check_continue):
    x.input()
    x.h()
    check = input('Want to continue? (Y/N): \n')

check_qr = input('Do you want to create a QR Code? (Y/N): \n')

if if_yes(check_qr) == True:
    filename = str(input("Enter file name: "))+".png"
    qrcode.make(x.blobchang).save(filename)
    print("Your file name is: ", filename)

print('Thank you for working with BlobChang!')
```

However, it stopped only at the first conditional statement and went into a loop. Why did that happen?

Comment: When importing a module, all its first-level code is executed, so it's very much expected.  As for going into a loop, this is exactly what your code does, there's no exit from `while` loop whatsoever.

Comment: Agreeing with Klas, I'd add that you should avoid first-level code in modules, or at least put that code in a `main` function as described here: https://realpython.com/python-main-function/

Comment: This is very helpful guys, thank you so much! So basically whenever I decide to import a class, all code from the source file will be executed and this is a normal thing, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `check_continue` is never updated that's why the condition in `while if_yes(check_continue):` always remains true and the code goes into an infinite loop, maybe you want `check_continue = input('Want to continue? (Y/N): \n')` in line 5

Comment: That's not the problem, in the original script everything works fine. The problem is that I DON'T want to execute the remaining script. I just want to import the BlobChang class and work with this class.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I only should define my BlobChang class in the BlobChang.py and then write the rest of the script in my import_test file?